# web api core 2 post internal error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi I am using vs 2017 on windows 7 I am following [this](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=asp-dotnet-core-api-building-first&author=kevin-dockx&name=asp-dotnet-core-api-building-first-m3&clip=1&mode=live) tutorial on plural sight :.net core 2 web api. The GET method work fine.There is internal server error 500. I appreciate any one detecting the source of this error. I am using Postman / Fiddler both of which give same 500 error:
[image]

```
 [HttpPost("{cityid}/pointofinterest", Name = "GetPointOfInterest")]
    public IActionResult CreatePointofInterest(int cityid, [FromBody]
    PointofInterestForCreationtDto inputPointofinterest)
    {

        if (inputPointofinterest == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var theCity = (CitiesRepo.Current.Cities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == cityid));
        if (theCity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        //get new id
      var maxid=  CitiesRepo.Current.Cities.SelectMany(
                         c => c.PointsOfInterest).Max(p => p.Id);

        var postedPointofInterest = new PointOfInterestDto()
        {
            Id = ++maxid,
            Name = inputPointofinterest.Name,
            Description = inputPointofinterest.Description
        };
        theCity.PointsOfInterest.Add(postedPointofInterest);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetPointOfInterest",
            new { CityId= cityid, id = postedPointofInterest.Id, postedPointofInterest });

    }
```

Comment: Hint: use the preview tab to actually read the error.

Comment: thanks this is the error:An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

CitiesInfo.Api.Controllers.CitiesController.CreatePointofInterest (CitiesInfo.Api)
CitiesInfo.Api.Controllers.PointofInterestController.CreatePointofInterest (CitiesInfo.Api)
M

Comment: you are right: I got error that there is another metthod with same route and signature

Answer (score 0):

@kogibail 500 Internal Server error is thrown usually when there is an unhandled exception (like a null reference exception) inside your block of code.

In your code, few null checks are needed. For instance, CitiesRepo.Current.Cities could either be checked for null if they can be null, or can be validated as

var theCity = CitiesRepo.Current?.Cities?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == cityid);

Include a try catch block and return the exception message to identify the root cause. Once you have fixed the exception, remove the try catch.

Comment: While this is sound advice, quite right in stating that the `try..catch` should be removed if added, it is better to learn how to use the debugger and avoid writing extra code to determine the cause of the error.

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpPost("{cityid}/pointofinterest", Name = "GetPointOfInterest")]
    public IActionResult CreatePointofInterest(int cityid, [FromBody]
    PointofInterestForCreationtDto inputPointofinterest)
    {

try
{

        if (inputPointofinterest == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var theCity = (CitiesRepo.Current.Cities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == cityid));
        if (theCity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        //get new id
      var maxid=  CitiesRepo.Current.Cities.SelectMany(
                         c => c.PointsOfInterest).Max(p => p.Id);

        var postedPointofInterest = new PointOfInterestDto()
        {
            Id = ++maxid,
            Name = inputPointofinterest.Name,
            Description = inputPointofinterest.Description
        };
        theCity.PointsOfInterest.Add(postedPointofInterest);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetPointOfInterest",
            new { CityId= cityid, id = postedPointofInterest.Id, postedPointofInterest });
}
catch(Exception e)
{
return { Error = e.Message }
}    }
```

Comment: my bad: I had the same method in a second controller with the same route type....I removed it and it is working now